# How to recursively objectify a string

Tags: javascript, recursion

While trying to become more comfortable with recursive functions, I attempted to write a function that takes a dot-separated string and converts that into an object.
So, given the following string: `user.first.name.robert` this function should return the following object:

```js
{
  user: {
    first: {
      name: 'robert'
    }
  }
}
```

Here's my attempt:

```js
function objectifyHelper(array, object) {
    if (array.length === 2) {
        const [key, value] = array;
        object[key] = value;
        return object;
    } else {
        object[array[0]] = objectifyHelper(array.slice(1), object); 
        return object;
    }
}

function objectify(string) {
    const tokens = string.split('.');
    return objectifyHelper(tokens, {});
}

const str = 'user.first.name.robert';
const result = objectify(str);
```

This gets me the following result:

```js
result <ref *1> {
  name: 'robert',
  first: [Circular * 1],
  user: [Circular * 1]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're only creating a single `object`. You'll need to create a new object (`{}`) for every level. Easiest if you just discard the `object` parameter of your function.

Comment: Btw, your base case is also not the base. `objectify('robert')` (without dots) should just return a single string. (And further, `objectifyHelper` should throw an exception when passed an empty array, instead of recursing endlessly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. However, if your helper accepts an object but also returns it, be consistent in your recursive call

```js
function objectifyHelper(array, object) {
    if (array.length === 2) {
        const [key, value] = array;
        object[key] = value;
        return object;
    } else {
        object[array[0]] = objectifyHelper(array.slice(1), {}); 
        return object;
    }
}

function objectify(string) {
    const tokens = string.split('.');
    return objectifyHelper(tokens, {});
}

const str = 'user.first.name.robert';
const result = objectify(str);

console.log(result)
```

Note that this only changes your

```
object[array[0]] = objectifyHelper(array.slice(1), object);
```

to

```
object[array[0]] = objectifyHelper(array.slice(1), {});
```

Reading OP's comment under the question, I believe it's fair to further expand the answer.

Yes, passing the newly created object to the recursive function and then returning it is could be simplified. One of possible approaches would be to remove the need to pass the object into the function and just return a newly created object to the caller.

Thus, a simplified version would be

```js
function objectifyHelper(array) {
    // we always create a new object
    var object = {};
    if (array.length === 2) {
        const [key, value] = array;
        object[key] = value;
    } else {    
        object[array[0]] = objectifyHelper(array.slice(1)); 
    }
    // and return it
    return object;
}

function objectify(string) {
    const tokens = string.split('.');
    return objectifyHelper(tokens);
}

const str = 'user.first.name.robert';
const result = objectify(str);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Your response and @CertainPerformance have helped me understand quite a bit.
The key was `if your helper accepts an object but also returns it, be consistent in your recursive call`. I was trying to mix two concepts at the same time, the one of passing an object as an initial value of a `reduce` function to build the object and recursion. It turns out that `objectifyHelper` doesn't need an object really.

Comment: @DataCrusader: I've expanded the answer to reflect your suggestion that the object doesn't have to be both passed into and returned from the method.

Answer (score 2):

You're only ever creating a single object here:

```
return objectifyHelper(tokens, {});
```

that then gets used every time a property is assigned to it. You need to instead create a new object when recursing, and not only inside of `objectify`.

A simpler approach would be:

```js
const objectify = string => string
  .split('.')
  .reduceRight(
    (innerObj, prop) => ({ [prop]: innerObj })
  );

const str = 'user.first.name.robert';
const result = objectify(str);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Learned quite a bit from this. Thank you.